# Any problem declaring a variable and using TryParse to initialize it on same line?

Tags: c#, initialization, declaration

This example is in C# but I expect could apply to others just as easily.

I recently found that the following seems to work just fine:

```
int i = Int32.TryParse(SomeString, out i) ? i : -1;
```

Somehow it seems as though the variable `i` shouldn't technically be accessible at the point it appears in `TryParse`. Or would I be correct to assume that `int i` effectively declares the variable, even though there is no end of statement yet?

Comment: Ha! That is so cool. This code is no good if -1 is a valid value of SomeString, but still. I often wish I could declare an "out" variable implicitly, e.g. wouldn't it be nice if you could write `if (int.TryParse(s, out var i)) {...}` where `i` is a new variable that was never declared previously?

Comment: Perhaps, as Henk suggests, a helper method is best. for example, `int CustomIntParse(string s, int default) {}`

Comment: I've taken a shot at some helper methods to consider.

Comment: You can do it but it's not very efficient. If TryParse() returns true, i gets assigned twice. Hey, I'm all for reducing the amount of code, but not at the expense of efficient code.

Comment: @Jonathan Seriously, this is likely to be a drop in the ocean as i will be in a register anyway. It's beyond a micro optimisation in the shadow of parsing an int.

Comment: @chibacity: Well, if you wrote all your code with that mindset, it would start to add up. Sure, if you gain something, we all give up performance here and there. But what's to gain here? Squeezing everything on one line? I don't get it.

Comment: @Jonathan I agree 100% on the "it all adds up", this is just not a significant performance case by a long shot. The readability is the important issue here. Whilst the 'TryX' pattern introduces a pattern which performs better and tends to produce safer code than the old try\catch pattern, it feels ugly handling the out parameter style. The OP is trying to contend with this.

Comment: @chibacity: I guess different programmers will have strong opinions about their preferred way of doing things. I agree Parse() looks cleaner. But, for me, trying to make TryParse() look like an assignment like Parse() just makes it harder to see what is really happening.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`int i` declares the variable, and using it in the `out` parameter initializes it.  Since the predicate must be evaluated before the consequent, `i` is therefore both declared and initialized before use.  (`out` parameters must be assigned before returning, so it is definitely initialized in any case.)

That said, there are colleagues of mine that would throw a fit at seeing something like that on style grounds. :-)

**EDIT:** After surveying how this has shaken out, I'll propose a couple of possible alternative helper methods.  Naming of the static class acts as intention documentation for the helper methods here.

```
internal static class TryConvert
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the integer result of parsing a string, or null.
    /// </summary>
    internal static int? ToNullableInt32(string toParse)
    {
        int result;
        if (Int32.TryParse(toParse, out result)) return result;
        return null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the integer result of parsing a string,
    /// or the supplied failure value if the parse fails.
    /// </summary>
    internal static int ToInt32(string toParse, int toReturnOnFailure)
    {
        // The nullable-result method sets up for a coalesce operator.
        return ToNullableInt32(toParse) ?? toReturnOnFailure;
    }
}

internal static class CallingCode
{
    internal static void Example(string someString)
    {
        // Name your poison. :-)
        int i = TryConvert.ToInt32(someString, -1);
        int j = TryConvert.ToNullableInt32(someString) ?? -1;

        // This avoids the issue of a sentinel value.
        int? k = TryConvert.ToNullableInt32(someString);
        if (k.HasValue)
        {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's why I pose the question. I am always seeking to simplify code (at least to the point it remains readable). I feel this statement is readable, but could you elaborate on style considerations?

Comment: @JYelton Some people find ternary operators less readable for starters. Then there's the fact that there's the use of the side-effect of the out parameter to initialize i before the ternary branch assignment. If you have to ask a question on SO whether there's any problems doing this, you've answered your readability question. :)

Comment: I'm one of those who would throw a fit on style grounds. Whereas it works, it looks confusing. It's not immediately obvious what's going on, so I have to play compiler to figure it out.

Answer (score 4):

> I recently found that the following seems to work just fine

```
 int i = Int32.TryParse(SomeString, out i) ? i : -1;
```

It works, but it is not fine.

> Any problem declaring a variable and using TryParse to initialize it on same line?

Yes, readability. I think this looks awful, and it is doing double work.

---

Part of your problem is that you want `-1` as your default. Int32.TryParse explicitly defines `0` as the out value when conversion fails.

I would still break it up in 2 lines for readability's sake.

```
int i;
if (! int.TryParse(SomeString, out i))  i = -1;
```

And when you need this a lot, write a (static but not extension) helper method:

```
int i = Utils.ParseInt(SomeString, -1);
```

Comment: Would you simply break this into separate lines of code? Or is there another concise way to set an int to a parsed value of a string, and specify a default value for parse failure?

Comment: I like the static helper method. Makes it obvious what's happening.

Comment: The static helper method is a great idea. When using a construct often, I usually create a utility method somewhere. Thanks for the input.

Comment: So, why not as an extension method?

Answer (score 4):

Remember that there is no ternary operator in CIL.

```
int i = Int32.TryParse(SomeString, out i) ? i : -1;
```

Your code is transformed into CIL representing the following C# code:

```
int i;
if (Int32.TryParse(SomeString, out i))
  i = i;
else
  i = -1;
```

Which is perfectly fine.

Comment: This makes it more clear that if I insisted on keeping this structure, at the very least I should invert the if statement so that `i` is only set upon failure (shown in Henk's example). Thanks.